# Django Middleware: How do I access a view's params from middleware

Tags: django, django-middleware

Let's say I have a view:

```
def pony_view(request, arg1, arg2):
    ... Make ponies, etc ...
```

And a middleware:

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(request):
        # How do I access arg1, arg2 here?
```

Of course arg1, and arg2 will be passed in via URL params with urls.py.

The reason I need to do this is because I want to add something to request.session before the view function runs (something that I need from the URL though).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to implement the [`process_view`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) method.

It has this signature:

```
process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs)
```

and is executed before the view function is called:

> `process_view()` is called just before Django calls the view. It should return either `None` or an `HttpResponse` object. If it returns `None`, Django will continue processing this request, executing any other `process_view()` middleware and, then, the appropriate view. If it returns an `HttpResponse` object, Django won't bother calling ANY other request, view or exception middleware, or the appropriate view; it'll return that `HttpResponse`. Response middleware is always called on every response.

Then you should be able to access `arg1` and `arg2` with:

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        arg1, arg2 = view_args[:2]
```

Comment: I need to access the view before `process_view` is called, because I need to 
stop processing other middlewares in the chain given some condition that depends on a flag stored in the view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read GET parameters from URL you can use request.GET dictionary:

```
class MyMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        print(request.GET)  # immutable QueryDict
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access URL parameters in the middleware's `__call__`, `process_request` or `process_response` methods by using `resolve()` like this:

```
from django.urls import resolve

class MyMiddleware:
  def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

  def __call__(self, request):
    match = resolve(request.path_info)
    arg1, arg2 = match.args[:2]

    # do something with arg1, arg2

    return self.get_response(request)
```